# How to use Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to separate a string like this:

```
C-USD10.00_FRIES AND BURGUER_USD15.00
```

In groups like this

```
segment = first_char;
subtotal_currency = after-next_3_chars;
subtotal = digits_up_to_;
description = text_up_to_;
total_curency = next_3_char;
total = last_digits;
```

I guess that one way to represent it is this:

```
 (?P<segment>[A-Z])-(?P<scurr>[A-Z]{3})(?P<subtotal>\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?)_(?<desc>^\s*[a-zA-Z,\s]+\s*$)_(?P<curr>[A-Z]{3})(?P<total>\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?)
```

The expected result would be:

```
segment = "C";
subtotal_currency = "USD";
subtotal = 10.00;
description = "FRIES AND BURGUER";
total_curency = "USD";
total = 15.00;
```

How can I make use of regular expressions in java to make the division of the string in that way?

By the way, I have to make this job for many types of strings... so I guess using regular expressions will help me a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to goggle "java regex example"?

Comment: hi, yes but I can't find an example in which they use named groups. It is what i'm trying to do...

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need named groups specifically?

Comment: there are a lot of types of strings and I have to parse them all; Im a python programmer and I have made something like this using named groups. This time I'm doing it with Java. I guess it is because of that. But if you have a better way, i would gladly read it.

Comment: It's a bit harder in Java to loop all named groups. I was just wondering why you needed them and the syntax is `(?<named>..)`. Anyway, I'd suggest correcting some things in your pattern first. You're using a comma to match a dot, and you have `^` and `$` in the middle of your pattern that will never match. Also, you need to escape each backslash in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes are in the java.util.regex package.

Looks like you have the right idea. Based on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for the Pattern and Matcher classes, the only thing you need to remove from your pattern is the Ps between the ? and the < for the named group, something like this:

`(?<segment>[A-Z])-(?<scurr>[A-Z]{3})(?<subtotal>\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?)_(?<desc>^\s*[a-zA-Z,\s]+\s*$)_(?<curr>[A-Z]{3})(?<total>\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?)`

Create your Pattern object, then call .matcher() on the String to get the Matcher. Then you can extract the info from the Matcher with the .group(String) method.

You could easily make the system generic, but helpful to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?P<segment>[A-Z])-(?P<scurr>[A-Z]{3})(?P<subtotal>\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)_(?<desc>\s*[a-zA-Z,\s]+\s*)_(?P<curr>[A-Z]{3})(?P<total>\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)
                                                          ^^                                                                           ^^
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3mH8/2

Issues:

1)added `.` along with `,`.

2)Removed `^$` from middle string.